# Getting type that pointer type is pointing to

Tags: c++, templates

I wanted to make helper struct that would contain typedef of type, that template pointer parameter is pointing to:

```
template<class T*>
struct pointer_lower_level
{
    typedef typename T type_pointed;
};
```

But it gives me errors (GCC 5.3.0):

```
error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'T'
     typedef typename T type_pointed;
                      ^
error: expected ';' at end of member declaration

error: 'type_pointed' does not name a type
     typedef typename T type_pointed;
                        ^
```

To me it looks like legal syntax, but well, I had very long day so I may be wrong.

Comment: I don't know why you're implementing your own, so if it's so you can use it, just FYI: [the standard library has `std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to use [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer), I think what you want is to use a [*partial template specialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

```
template <typename>
struct pointer_lower_level;

template <typename T>
struct pointer_lower_level<T*> {
    using type_pointed = T;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a template specialization:

```
// first declare the general template...
template<class T>
struct pointer_lower_level;

// ...then provide a partial specialization for pointers
template<class T>
struct pointer_lower_level<T*>
// note this... ----------^^^^
{
    typedef T type_pointed;
};
```